# Appium Flutter automation: How to record the video session of the current test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io

We're using appium-flutter-driver for automating our flutter/hybrid mobile application, and we're using mocha as a testing framework. Now we need to record the video session of our automation script session locally. We try to use [test-video-recorder](https://github.com/jaredblumer/test-video-recorder), but we can't record it.

Attached is a sample code for reference:

```
const VideoRecorder = require('test-video-recorder')
VideoRecorder.setPath(path.join(__dirname, "/logs"));

describe("Automation test", async () => {

beforeEach(function getTestTitle() {
    functionName = this.currentTest.title
    VideoRecorder.start(functionName, 'mocha')
})

it('TC001', async () => {
    //Test block
})

afterEach(function getTestStatus() {
    VideoRecorder.stop()
})

}.timeout(9000);
```

How can we record video of the current driver session using a test-video-recorder or other means?